# Use cell's value as part of macro

Tags: excel, variables, range, cell, defined

I usually use a macro to show and hide columns using a checkbox.
I set it up by defining the columns in the macro code.

> ```
> Sub Hideshow()
>     If Range("A1").Value = "True" Then
>         ActiveSheet.Columns("B:C").Hidden = False
>     ElseIf Range("A1").Value = "False" Then
>         ActiveSheet.Columns("B:C").Hidden = True
>     Else
>     Return
>     End If
>     End Sub
> ```

For this code, A1 = the result of the checkbox (True/False)
and B:C are the columns I am hiding or, if already hidden; showing.

However, now I am making a more dynamic version of this, because I am getting bored of scrolling through the macro code and changing each column reference when a new column is added or the column range changes.

I have now put the columns I want to hide within cell A2 on my sheet
e.g     B:C

I would like the macro code to use the value of that cell as a 'defined range'? to show and hide the column range I have defined in cell A2.

I've found lots of similar posts, but they are slightly different and I can't make it work for my specific scenario.

The new one would look something like this

> ```
> Sub Hideshow()
>     If Range("A1").Value = "True" Then
>         ActiveSheet.Columns(" The Value in A2 ").Hidden = False
>     ElseIf Range("A1").Value = "False" Then
>         ActiveSheet.Columns(" The Value in A2").Hidden = True
>     Else
>     Return
>     End If
>     End Sub
> ```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should do the trick:

```
Sub HideShow()

    Dim ColsToHide As String
    ColsToHide = Sheet1.Range("A2") 'This will always get the value from the sheet with the codename Sheet1.

    'Unhide if hidden, hide if not hidden.
    ActiveSheet.Columns(ColsToHide).Hidden = Not ActiveSheet.Columns(ColsToHide).Hidden

End Sub
```

There are probably better ways to figure out which columns need hiding - is there anything specific about a column that decides if it should be hidden or not?

Comment: Thankyou Darren. Not only does this simplify my original macro - but it answers the question. I haven’t tried it yet, but pretty sure it will work. Does the Dim title need to be specific name or is this a custom title? I plan to set the macro to be ‘active sheet’ rather than a specficified sheet.

Comment: No, you can use pretty much any word you want as a variable.  Avoid words that VBA uses already such as `Workbook`, `Value`, `Name`, etc.. (When you say Dim title I take it you mean the `ColsToHide` bit).